# Riemann matrix function optimization in Julia

Tags: matrix, compiler-optimization, julia

I have implemented a function in Julia for creating a Riemann matrix of size N. It is a N-by-N matrix associated with the Riemann hypothesis, which is true if and only if:

`DET(A) = O( N! N^(-1/2+epsilon))` for every `epsilon > 0`, `DET()` denotes determinant, `!` denotes factorial.

Where, A = Riemann matrix, with

`A = B(2:N+1, 2:N+1)`, where

```
B(i,j) = i-1 if i divides j, and
          -1 otherwise.
```

Here is my code which works fine, but needs optimization:

```
function riemann(x::Int32)
    R = zeros(Int32,x+1,x+1)
    for i=1:x+1, j=1:x+1
        if j%i == 0
           R[i,j] = i-1
        else
           R[i,j] = -1
        end
    end
    return R[2:x+1,2:x+1]
end
```

Hopefully, I need to write it in a more efficient form like:

```
function riemann!{T}(R::AbstractMatrix{T}, x::T)
.
.
.
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

EDIT:

Well, this is the other form I suggested above. I timed it against the original code and found no speed gain.

```
function calc_riemann!{T}(R::AbstractMatrix{T}, x::T)
    for i=1:x+1, j=1:x+1
        if j%i == 0
           R[i,j] = i-1
        else
           R[i,j] = -1
        end
    end
end
function riemann(x::Int)
    R = Array(Int, x+1,x+1)
    calc_riemann!(R, x)
    y = R[2:x+1,2:x+1]
end
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what the question is.

Comment: The question is how to optimize the above function for efficient memory usage and ultimate speed.

Comment: If you made the `Int32`s into `Int`s, I doubt you could get this much faster. It looks like with the `riemann!` version you are proposing to allocate the matrix outside the function, but that wouldn't change the total time.

Comment: Right IainDunning, I implemented the `riemann!(...` form without gaining any extra speed. See my updated post. So any more suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works much faster by cutting out all of the tests (we can just step to the multiples).

```
function my_riemann(x::Int)
    R = Array(Int,x+1,x+1)
    fill!(R,-1)
    for i=2:x+1
        for j=i:i:x+1
            R[i,j] = i - 1
        end
    end
    return R[2:x+1,2:x+1]
end
```

***EDIT***

Yeah, allocating the right size `Array` and not copying it speeds things up dramatically.  See if your time for this version is reduced considerably.

```
function my_riemann2(x::Int)
    R = Array(Int,x,x)
    fill!(R,-1)
    for i=1:x
        for j=i:i+1:x
            R[i,j] = i
        end
    end
    return R
end
```

Comment: Probably don't need to allocate an `Array` that's bigger than the return value either.  I'll leave that to you to see if that speeds it up much.

Comment: Many thanks, this is about 4.4x faster than mine. It is not clear to me what you mean by allocating array that is bigger than the return value! I see that R is bigger than the return value by only one row and one column. Also what is the difference between `Int` and `Int32`? in performance I mean.

Comment: Currently, `R[2:x+1,2:x+1]` will make a copy, so avoiding that could indeed make a difference. `Int` will be a `typealias` for either `Int32` or `Int64` depending on if you are using 32 bit or 64 bit julia.

Comment: So, this has nothing to do with performance. It is only for compatibility reasons. As if you are willing to submit that code to another person with different Julia than you. Am I right?

Comment: I mean `Int` and `Int32`

Comment: @Power_Project @Toivo-Henningsson  See EDIT above.  Right-sizing the `Array` speeds it up a lot on my platform.

Comment: Well @rickhg12hs, that is about 9.4x faster than my original code. Unforunately, I still dont have enough credits to up-vote you!! Many thanks.